# How to fix this error : " array to string conversion "?

Tags: php, arrays, string, error-handling

I'm coding my web app in PHP and when I run my script, I've got this error :
array to string conversion

Here is the script where the error fires.

```
public function insert($table, array $columns, array $values) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table .
                    " (" . implode(',' , $columns) . " ) 
                    VALUES (" . implode(',',
                    $values) . ")";
            $this->request($sql);
    }
```

Here is the request function :

```
public function request($sql, $param = null) {
        if ($param == null) {
            $query = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->query($sql);
        }

        else {
           $query = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($sql);
           $query->execute(array($param));
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

N.B : I'm using my own MVC framework.

So, any advise or help would be apreciated ?

Regards

YT

Comment: Do yourself a favour and start using prepared statements. They're available for most RDBMS and are supported by both the _mysqli_ and _PDO_ APIs.

Comment: Also, which line of code is giving you that error? Your query looks like it should produce a valid string. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfedfd616bd3620d67a2e65d6e8b8a5ec012f96c

Comment: Sorry, just saw your request method is using a prepared statement if you pass through `$params`. Why aren't you passing through params in this case? I'd change your _insert_ statements so that it generates `INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)` and then pass through the values as `$params`.

Comment: Look my code here https://phpize.online/?phpses=dc933a50abe8b080153673519efa9b32&sqlses=eae5065c8b4eaf560cf79cc4f4be5ee6&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57 Can it halp you?

Answer (score 1):

I advice to modify your class methods for using parameterized queries:

```php
class Test {
    public function insert($table, array $columns, array $values) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode(',' , $columns) . ") 
                VALUES (?" . str_repeat(",?", count($columns) - 1) . ");";

        echo $sql;
        $this->request($sql, $values);
    }
    
    public function request($sql, $param = null) {
        if ($param == null) {
            $query = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->query($sql);
        }

        else {
           $query = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($sql);
           $query->execute($param);
        }

        return $query;
    }   
};

$test = new Test();

$test->insert('tbl', ['id', 'name'], [1, 'first row']);
```

[Online PHP test](https://phpize.online/?phpses=6650b5c5e2f2155614ca94b4e960ac10&sqlses=eae5065c8b4eaf560cf79cc4f4be5ee6&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)